# How determine if Java object is null or not in Tasker?

Tags: sms, tasker, java

I want a Tasker task that reads SMS from a particular person and extracts some information out of the latest message.

For example, I get a lot of messages from my bank due to the transactions I make. At the touch of a task, I want to know my latest bank balance. Normally, I would get the latest SMS from my bank and find out the balance from it. I want Tasker to do this.

I am aware that Tasker can read messages when they arrive. But we have to make a profile that does it. This is not my use-case. It's more on-demand.

Here is the task I tried to create to that effect:

```
Flash Roam (10)
    A1: Java Function [ Return:cr Class Or Object:CONTEXT Function:getContentResolver
{ContentResolver} () Param: Param: Param: Param: Param: Param: Param: ] 
    A2: If [ cr !Set ]
    A3: Flash [ Text:Ok Long:Off ] 
    A4: End If
```

I am unable to ascertain if `cr` is null or not.

What is the correct way to check it? Or is this even possible in Tasker?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do null checking of Java objects.

---

The first way, direct from [the userguide](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/java.html#support), is checking of the object `Equals null`:

> ## If
>
> A Java object can be directly referenced in a condition. Null-value objects are replaced with text representation `null`.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> If, arr[0][0] eq 45
> If, arr[0].length > 3 
> If, lightlevel Equals null
> ```

The problem with this is that the *string* "null" will also match the condition. In your case, that's not a concern, but my second method provides a way that can distinguish between the two for other cases.

---

The second way takes advantage of Tasker's built-in error checking. If you have an object and need to check whether or not it's null:

1. Use a Java Function action. For "Object or Class", use the object in question, then for "Function" select "toString {String} ()"*. Lastly, make sure "Continue Task After Error" is checked. You don't need a return value here.
2. Follow the Function with an If action, which tests if the variable `%err` is set (or isn't set).
3. If `%err` is set, the object is null. Otherwise, it's not null.

`%err` will not be set if the object is the string "null", because `"null".toString()` is perfectly valid code.

* If your only option in the Function list is "assign {...} ()", then you're working with a primitive type - a number, boolean, or character. Those can't be null, so checking is unnecessary.